# Debugging war file in tomcat6

Tags: tomcat, war

Here http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/1242473 i found that in order to configure tomcat to run war file in debug mode I have to add this "`set JPDA_OPTS=-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:server=y,transport=dt_socket,address=8000,suspend=n`" line somewhere in my tomcat configurations.

**where exactly I should put configuration line which helps tomcat 6 to understand that I want to start war file in debug mode?**

Tomcat6 32bit windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to place this `set JPDA_OPTS=-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:server=y,transport=dt_socket,address=8000,suspend=n` line in "Java control panel"->"Java"->"View"->"User" and "System" Java "Runtime Parameters" field.

Answer (score 0):

In the `catalina.sh` (bat) file.

Answer (score 0):

The environment variables are usually set in a script called setenv.sh or setenv.bat.
You will also need to add jpda in the command line that launches tomcat in startup.sh (.bat):

exec "$PRGDIR"/"$EXECUTABLE" **jpda** start "$@"

or:

call "%EXECUTABLE%" **jpda** start %CMD_LINE_ARGS%